# Jquery click span doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

1. it doesn't run when finished whole pages. i don't know why ?
2. how i do it when finished loading whole pages i want to run onload function.

thanks all.

```html
<html>
                      <head>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                      </head>
                      <body>
                        <body>
                            <div>
                              <div><span id="exid">Hello</span></div>
                            </div>
                      </body>
                    <script>
                        window.onload = function() { 
                          $('#exid').on('click', function(){
                            alert('2');
                          });
                        }; 
                        </script>
                    </html>
```

Comment: When I run your code snippet (using the blue button "Run code snippet"), clicking the "Hello" label does show an alert (expected behavior). So what's the problem?

Comment: Do you need the alert on load (not on click) function ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if I understand what you mean, but I think it could be this...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div><span id="exid">Hello</span></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // This will be executed when you click in the span.
                $('#exid').on('click',function() {
                    alert('2');
                });

                // If you want to execute the same code of the click when the page 
                // is loaded, you can just trigger the created click event.
                $('#exid').trigger('click');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practices is to put your `js` code at the bottom before the ending `</body>` tag so the `html` loads first then read it by your `js` code, like so:

**If you want the click event**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <span id="exid">Hello</span>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#exid').click(function(){
        alert('Clicked!');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**If you only want an alert when the page load**

```html
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <span id="exid">Hello</span>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          alert('2');
        });
      </script>
    </body>
```